# Existence of a triangle with altitudes' length 4, 6 and 8 cm

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

Does it exist a triangle with altitude height 4, 6 and 8 cm?
I have found that its sides have ratios 2:3:4 and hence if such a triangle exists it should be an obtuse triangle.

Comment: You already answered yourself

Comment: you have $2a=3b=4c=$ area of the triangle.

Comment: Are you looking for the Cartesian coordinates of the three points or something? Side lengths?

Comment: The problem that I need to answer is if it is possible to have a triangle with altitudes height 4, 6 and 8 cm?

Comment: Heron's formula gives the area in terms of $a,b,c$. We have $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns. Solving we get the $3$ sides of such a triangle thereby proving existence